# SQL - All rows that contain 2 specific values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently querying a database that looks like this..

ID1    ID2     ID3     ID4      ID5    ID6

1

2

3

4

I basically want to pull all rows where "808" AND "205" is in the ID Columns? So rows where they are BOTH contained in the columns, it doesn't matter which columns they are in as long as they both exist on one row if that makes sense?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: How many ID columns are there in your table?

Comment: what if they repeat like 808 205 808

Comment: sorry to say this, but I think you need to sit down and rethink your design.

Answer (score 4):

Your table is not normalized, so I would suggest you to normalize, this will make thinks easier in the future, however I understand that sometimes we have to deal with not normalized data.

Your query could look like this:

```
select
  *
from
  tablename
where
  '808' in (ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5,ID6)
  and
  '205' in (ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5,ID6)
```